# Full universal boilerplate for react redux

Tags: react-redux

I didn't find any good boilerplate, as I want. I need boilerplate with:

- React
- Redux
- Express
- Routering
- Server-side rendering
- Thunk middleware
- Hot reload
- Css-modules
- Webpack
- Babel
- Eslint
- Dev and Prod mods

I didn't find anything in all github! Making it yourself is very very complicated - many errors, stupid things! I spent 2 monthes for this and didn't achieve the desired result.

Comment: Try create react app or kriasoft react boilerplate

Comment: I don't need GraphQL and other complicated things

Comment: This is exactly what I need also, anyone find anything?

Answer (score 2):

I *strongly* recommend working through this: https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch

Aside from the fact that it covers everything you asked for an more, this repository *actually walks you through the setup of your own 'boilerplate'* which is a far more valuable tool in the long run.

I have a simple boilerplate repo that I built up based on that repo here: https://github.com/savish/sample-js-app